# How to iterate the child HTML elements of an uncle element

Tags: javascript, jquery, foreach

I have a list element (`<ul>`). I want to iterate with jQuery's `each()` all `<li>` children of an uncle element of the input element.

Here is my code:

```js
let clname = "Hadiselect0";
let ar = ($('.dd-search .' + clname)[0].parentNode.parentNode + '+ ul >li');
ar.each(function () {
   console.log("ok");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="list">
   <div class="dd-search">
     <input id="txtSearchValue" autocomplete="off" class="dd-searchbox Hadiselect0" type="text">
   </div>

   <ul>
      <li class="option selected" data-value="0" data-display-text="" tabindex="0">please select</li>
      <li class="option " data-value="6565666" data-display-text="" tabindex="0">4623526615</li>
      <li class="option " data-value="6565666" data-display-text="" tabindex="0">4623526615</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

This code has produces the following error:

> ar.each is not a function

How can I make it work?

Comment: I think you might have forgotten the `$` before your statement: `$($('.dd-search .' + clname)[0].parentNode.parentNode + '+ ul >li')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the jQuery `.find()` method:

```js
let clname = "Hadiselect0";

let ar = $('.dd-search .' + clname).parent().parent().find('ul > li');
ar.each(function () {
    console.log("ok", $(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list">
   <div class="dd-search">
      <input id="txtSearchValue" autocomplete="off" class="dd-searchbox Hadiselect0" type="text">
   </div>

   <ul>
      <li class="option selected" data-value="0" data-display-text="" tabindex="0">please select</li>
      <li class="option " data-value="6565666" data-display-text="" tabindex="0">4623526615</li>
      <li class="option " data-value="6565666" data-display-text="" tabindex="0">4623526615</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```